# Collada load in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I want to load collada file using three.js. I tried but the file is not showing. No error is also showing. I tried some other dae file but this dae file is not working. What's the issue i could not find. Is there problem with file or code ?

```
<script src="build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        var container, stats, clock;
        var camera, scene, renderer, elf;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 3000 );
            //camera.position.z = 3000;
            //camera.position.y = 150;
            camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            clock = new THREE.Clock();
            // loading manager
            var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {
                scene.add( elf );
            } );
            // collada
            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
            loader.load( 'textures/sketup/pack.dae', function ( collada ) {
                elf = collada.scene;
            } );
            //
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );
            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
            directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, 0 ).normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );
            //
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //
            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            stats.update();
        }
        function render() {
            var delta = clock.getDelta();
            if ( elf !== undefined ) {
                elf.rotation.y += delta * 0.5;
            }
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
```

I tried this code. But this code is not showing the collada file. What's the issue?
here is the file link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtPLq6DiFBkajVjRWJGaVBFSzNkbkdlQWdhMTkzQ0hQY0hR/view

Comment: _"Is there problem with file..."_ It's hard to investigate, having no file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtPLq6DiFBkajVjRWJGaVBFSzNkbkdlQWdhMTkzQ0hQY0hR
file link

Comment: @Falak Sabbir not able to download the file from the link.